# How do I drop complete rows (including all values in it) that contain a certain value in my Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a python script that finds unique values (names) and reports the frequency of their occurrence, making use of Pandas library. There's a total of around 90 unique names, which I've anonymised in the head of the dataframe pasted below.

```
,1,2,3,4,5
0,monday09-01-2022,tuesday10-01-2022,wednesday11-01-2022,thursday12-01-2022,friday13-01-2022
1,Anonymous 1,Anonymous 1,Anonymous 1,Anonymous 1,
2,Anonymous 2,Anonymous 4,Anonymous 5,Anonymous 5,Anonymous 5
3,Anonymous 3,Anonymous 3,,Anonymous 6,Anonymous 3
4,,,,,
```

I'm trying to drop any row (the full row) that contains the regex expression "^monday.*", intending to indicate the word "monday" followed by any other number of random characters. I want to drop/deselect any cell/value within that row.

To achieve this goal, I've tried using the line of code below (and many other approaches I found on SO).

`df = df[df[1].str.contains("^monday.*", case = True, regex=True) == False]`

To clarify, I'm trying to search values of column "1" for the value "^.monday.*" and then deselecting the rows and all values in that row that match the regex expression. I've succesfully removed "monday09-01-2022" and "tuesday10-01-2022" etc.. but I'm also losing random names that are not in the matching rows.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.